# GCE Instance terminated by guest OS shutdown

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a GCE instance running and was creating using the gcloud SDK. For some reason, each time a start such instance, this is stopped automatically without a logic reason.

I read the log and I'm the getting the following:

[Stackdrive Logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJJDj.png)

Would you have some recommendations of what would be the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: We don't know why your guest OS shutdown. That information would be inside the guest, but you configured it to terminate on shutdown, so it's not there anymore.

Comment: Ahmmm, I'm basically using the following source to try to set the VM instance ---> https://www.simoahava.com/google-cloud/scrape-domain-and-write-results-to-bigquery/#upload-the-configuration-to-gcs.

Comment: Does something from that article give a guess why this is shutdowning? I'm really kind of lost of where to go to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the **compute.instances.guestTerminate** event in the log appears that the instance's guest OS itself was the one which requested to shutdown / halt so the instance was terminated as a result. This could be due a command such as shutdown -h now inside the VM.

Regarding your provided document the VM instance will shut itself down when the crawl is complete:

[image]

Also, I recommend you to remove or hide your project ID and instance ID in your provided Stackdriver log as is visible in public.